# Can´t see resources folder, I created, in netBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I create, in NetBeans, a resources folder to store pictures in my project, but I cant see the folder in netbeans, but in the windows file explorer I can see it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you created it using windows file explorer, you may be to do "refresh" inside NetBeans. Don't know NetBeans, but in Eclipse you right-click the project and select "Refresh".

Comment: Where did you create it?  Did you create inside the `src` directory or in the project directory?  If you created in the project directory, you will need to switch to the "Files" view (instead of the "Project" view)

Comment: Yes! is there, so, I can only see it in the Filesview? that is normal?

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't require such shenanigans.  Get a better IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can try going to `Source > Scan for External Changes` option in your NetBeans.